# Wordpress all image's path change

Tags: php, image, wordpress

in my wordpress site suddenly something has changed and all the images of the website and blogs are not displaying instead image not found is appearing.

After checking the images path i found it as below for a single image.

```
<img src="http://www.kasthuri.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/mysql_logo.png" title="mysql_logo" alt="" data-imgh="340" data-imgw="930">
```

actually this is wrong, (path) it should be as following http://www.azraar.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/mysql_logo.png (**/blog/ is omitted**)

Then it does point to correct image. so i am wondering how can i change the entire images in my website to load without the /blog section in image path.

I also checked the db of wp.. found the **postmeta** table contains these images paths info but it doesnt contain in the entire paths.. it only has like this for all images.. **2012/02/mysql_logo.png**

any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `site url` is changed from

```
http://www.kasthuri.com/
```

to

```
http://www.kasthuri.com/blog/
```

So, changing the site url may solve your problem.

Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

In `database` it would be found in **wp_options** table